# Android Hide Notification from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to hide a notification which I receive from firebase through my api. Currently I am accessing the notification iny my MyFirebaseMessagingService like this:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_FILTER);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() != null) {
        setClientId(remoteMessage);
    }
}


private void setClientId(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();

    if (notification.getBody().equals("client_id")) {
        putClientIdToSharedPrefs((notification.getTitle()));
    }
}
```

I do not want to Show the message to the user in the Status bar, I just to receive the message and save it.

Comment: just remove the notification block , I think  you can't test it from the firebase panel

Comment: @OussemaAroua "remove the notification block"? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: as the answer below indicate

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you send from your API a notification object (which you probably do), the notification will be handled by the system.

So instead of sending:

```
"notification":{
 "title": "New Notification!",
 "body": "Test"
```

},

You can send:

```
"data":{
 "title": "New Notification!",
 "body": "Test"
```

},

That way, You will need to create the notification yourself if you want to show it to the user, but you will be able to catch the data.

Comment: So I Need to rename the object from "notification" to "data", ok I Need to test this asap :)

Comment: @Jonnotdoexx Yes, you cannot receive "notification" object if you want to handle displaying notification yourself.